# Iterar objeto dentro de objeto no Angular 8

Tags: html5, angular, typescript

gostaria de saber se é possível exibir um objeto dentro de outro no angular 8.

No caso eu tenho as propriedades do funcionário e dentro dele tem um objeto departamento com outras propriedades.

Eu gostaria de exibir os dados do funcionário e o nome do departamento que ele trabalha. Porém quando uso ngFor para iterar ou ele retorna [object Object] ou retorna campo em branco. E o funcionário tem o departamento cadastrado, po´rme não mostra na tela.
Abaixo as fotos das classes Funcionario e Departamento e do HTML da página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

A solução é bem simples na verdade.
O problema é que você está tentando imprimir o objeto em si, o que não é possível.

Basta você fazer assim:

```
<th>{{ func.departamento.nome }}</th>
```

Comment: Oi Josemar, então quando eu coloco desta forma 

<th>{{ func.departamento.nome }}</th> o campo fica em branco na tela, sem nenhuma informação.

Comment: Então o objeto não foi preenchido. Tente dar um `console.log` pra ver se está preenchido corretamente ou use um `{{ func.departamento.nome | json }}` para ver direto no template.

Comment: Realmente o objeto estava vazio. Na tela de cadastro eu não tinha colocado a propriedade no [value], tinha deixado como objeto.

Obrigado pela ajuda Josemar.